# wp_mail - using a custom field value

Tags: plugins, wp-mail, customization

Can this work? I want to send a email when a post is published to the recipient, that is called in custom field.

*EDIT* I changed the code to another example I found.

```
function wpr_Notification($post_id) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $to = get_post_meta($post_id, 'recipient', true);
    $headers = 'From: Disctopia Metal Webzine <admin@disctopia.de>';
    $title = $post->post_title." has been published";
    $message = " Hello ... and so on.... ";

    wp_mail($to, $title, $message, $headers); 
} 
add_action('publish_post', 'wpr_Notification');
```

Everything works smooth except for the recipient. If I put an static email adress into this field instead of $to, it works. But if I try to get the value of the custom field, it fails.

I tried to see whats the value of $to by putting it into the $message and changing the $to to my own email adress. Well, there was no value at all for the $to.

What is wrong with this variable? The custom field definitely is called "recipient" and is just a text-string.

:(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can work. But you should filter the email in the custom field. Users might have a error in his context or the mail address is wrong.

You can filter the email address with [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/function.filter-var.php)

Comment: Hi Frank, you have no idea how often your blog posts on your website have helped me. :-)

Well, I tried this code of me, but it didn't work. The inserted email adress is correct and the email was definitely not sent (looked even in my spam folder). Something must be wrong... :( Any clue? 

I would like to filter the adress, but I haven ever used this function. I am not used to PHP at all...

Comment: Thanks and welcome. How you include this code? set a `var_dump()` and output for debugging purpose all var from wp_mail() function to check.

Comment: I have put everything into my function.php within my theme-folder.
Shouldn't that work itself? D: filter and all that stuff sounds nice, but is beyond my knowlegde. ;-)

Comment: changed the root question :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function has a parameter called $post_id, but that parameter is not being passed to it. The get_post() function is not affected by this because the post ID is optional in it (the function will use the global $post to retrieve the post ID). However, for the get_post_meta() function the post ID is a requirement. If it is NULL (like I believe is happening in your example) the function will return an empty string. Since get_post() already retrieved the WP_POST object for you you can use it to get the post ID instead. Try this:

```
function wpr_Notification() {
    $post = get_post();
    $to = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recipient', true);
    $headers = 'From: Disctopia Metal Webzine <admin@disctopia.de>';
    $title = $post->post_title." has been published";
    $message = " Hello ... and so on.... ";

    wp_mail($to, $title, $message, $headers); 
} 
add_action('publish_post', 'wpr_Notification');
```

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress Development community =] . Since the `publish_post` action isn't fired in the loop, it's somewhat ambiguous as to the whether or not the `$post` global will be populated when this hook fires. But the callback *can* receive both the `$post_id` and `$post` itself as arguments - it's better to use these arguments to remove ambiguity. You're right about the callback not receiving these arguments, however - but the issue is easily resolved. Take a look at the `add_action()` call on the the [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post).